# Is any method in android to determine a remote socket is closed

Tags: java, android, sockets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [determine socket connection state - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604263/determine-socket-connection-state-android)

Actually i am a VC++ program developer.  Now i got an assignment in Android.  I am converting a VC++ program into android.  Is any method or function in android to determine whether a remote socket is closed

Answer (score 0):

There is no method in *TCP* to determine that a remote socket is closed. All you can do is read or write and deal with the boundary conditions.

Comment: How can i determine by read or write ?

Comment: @techcent If the peer has closed the connection properly, a `read()` `will return -1; a `readLine()` will return null; and `readXXX()` for any other X will throw `EOFException`. If you write to a connection that has already been closed by the peer, eventually you will get an `IOException: connection reset`. 'Eventually' is because of buffering and TCP retries: it doesn't happen on the first such write.